# I have seven methods in which I am calling alert function, is it possible i do call only one time alert function, so to optimize my code

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, optimization

I have six methods, in which I'm calling alert function.
Is it possible to call only the alert function only once, so to optimize my code will be?
This is my code:

```
// #import "ViewController.h"

//.h file 

.m file

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize usernameText;
@synthesize emailText;
@synthesize passwordText;
@synthesize `repasswordTex`t;
@synthesize postalText;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

//for keyboard hide on textfield return
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

//function for Name validation
- (BOOL) validatename:(NSString *) candidate{
    [postalText setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet];
    NSString *nameRegex = @"[A-Za-z]+";
    NSPredicate *codeTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",nameRegex];

    return [codeTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}

// email validation
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}

// password code validation
- (BOOL)paswordvalidation:(NSString *) candidate
{

}

// postal code validation
- (BOOL) validatecode: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *codeRegex = @"^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$";
  NSPredicate *codeTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", codeRegex];

    return [codeTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}



 //method call on submit button
    - (IBAction)submitButn:(id)sender{



     //user name method call
            if(![self validatename:usernameText.text])
            {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Ensure that you have insert character only"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                return;
            }
//Email Method Call
    else if(![self validateEmail:emailText.text])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Insert Valid Email Address"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
//Password validate Method Call

    else if([passwordText.text length] <6)//&& [repasswordText.text length] <= 6)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Password should contain minimun 6 "delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
     else if (![passwordText.text isEqualToString:repasswordText.text])
{
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"confirm password should be same"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
     }



     //Postal Code Method Call
             else if(!([self validatecode:postalText.text] ||[postalText.text length] <6))

                {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"postal Code should cotain 5 "delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                    return;
                }
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

@end

Answer (score 0):

Write this method and call where ever you want.

```
-(void)showAlert :(NSString *)alertTitleString WithAlertMessage :(NSString *)alertMessage{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:alertTitleString alertMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

}
```

Comment: I know you refactored it fro code but that return statement seems to be unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can, you even should! You just need to refactor it to a separate methods witch will receive a few attributes or (better option) an object with variables from which you could set a required values for the alert you want to show.

```
- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)alertTitle andMessage:(NSString *)alertMessage {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle message:alertMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

It could be than a way better but according to your case that will do what you want. **It is just extracting a method from your code.**

Comment: `self` doesn't necessarily want to be the delegate. What about localisation? Can we do better than this...

Comment: surely we can, but I think this is obvious and depends what he needs. I could add more parameters (for sure delegate). Feel free to propose an edit :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, add this method name in AppDelegate.h

```
-(void)alertFuction:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
```

Then add this function to AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)alertFuction:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        alert = nil;

        [delegate.window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

}
```

Then in any other view controller put this
.h file

```
@class AppDelegate
```

.m file

```
#import AppDelegate
```

in viewDidload method

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

then you can call the alert method by

```
[delegate alertFuction:@"title" message:@"message"];
```

Comment: Don't use the app delegate for this. The app delegate is for `delegation of application level event handling` - not arbitrary helper functions...

Answer (score 0):

How about a generalised helper class with class methods which cover a number of common scenarios (which you may obviously want to reconfigure / add to):

```
@implementation AlertHelper

+ (UIAlertView *)showAlertWithMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    [AlertHelper showAlertWithTitle:nil message:message delegate:nil cancelButton:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButton:nil];
}

+ (UIAlertView *)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
{
    [AlertHelper showAlertWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButton:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButton:nil];
}

+ (UIAlertView *)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id < UIAlertViewDelegate >)delegate cancelButton:(NSString *)cancel otherButton:(NSString *)other
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancel otherButtonTitles:(other ? @[ other ] : nil)];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

Note that the alert view is returned just in case it is required (say you need to automatically remove the alert view once an operation is complete).